# Two-factor authentication: why was I asked for my iPhone passcode after I entered the verification code?

Tags: iphone, two-factor-authentication

I signed into iCloud in my Mac and I was sent a verification code to my iPhone, which I entered in the Mac.  But then I was surprised to be asked for the iPhone passcode.
[image]

I then got this dialog box, what protected data would be unavailable?

This situation actually never happened again, but I keep asking myself: in what situation are you required to enter the iPhone passcode?

Answer (score 2):

Apple does not hold encryption keys to certain types of protected data held in iCloud such as passwords, health and home. You need to enter your passcode to allow this new device to decrypt your data.

Comment: Sorry mate, could you reword that? I don't understand you.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.  This happens when you have two-factor authentication enabled for your apple ID, you have your iPhone as a trusted device already, and then you sign into iCloud in a new device and, instead of using the verification code sent to the iPhone, you choose it to be sent on a text message to a trusted phone number on another phone (Apple or not).  After you enter the verification code, you're asked for the iPhone passcode.  The same happens if you have a mac as a trusted device and then sign into iCloud in an iPhone: you're asked for the Mac log in password.  I wonder now what would happen if you sign into a third or fourth apple device in this manner. I guess you'd be asked for the passcode or password for any of your trusted devices.